# Is there a way to figure out in which region a Google Cloud Storage bucket is hosted?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

NCBI (the National Center for Biotech Info) generously provided their data for 3rd parties to consume. The data is located in cloud buckets such as `gs://sra-pub-run-1/`. I would like to read this data without incurring additional costs, which I believe can be achieved by reading it from the same region as where the bucket is hosted. Unfortunately, I can't figure out in which region the bucket is hosted (NCBI mentions in their docs that's in the US, but not where in the US). So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to figure out in which region a bucket that I don't own, like `gs://sra-pub-run-1/` is hosted?
2. Is my understanding correct that reading the data from instances in the same region is free of charge? What if the GCS bucket is multi-region?

Doing a simple `gsutil ls -b -L` either provides no information (when listing a specific directory within `sra-pub-run-1` or I get a permission denied error if I try to list info on `gs://sra-pub-run-1/` directly using:

`gsutil -u metagraph ls  -b gs://sra-pub-run-1/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specify a specific Compute Engine zone as a bucket location, but all Compute Engine VM instances in zones within a given region have similar performance when accessing buckets in that region.

Billing-wise, egressing data from Cloud Storage into a Compute Engine instance in the same location/region (for example, US-EAST1 to US-EAST1) is free, regardless of zone.

So, check the "Location constraint" of the GCS bucket (`gsutil ls -Lb gs://bucketname` ), and if it says "US-EAST1", and if your GCE instance is also in US-EAST1, downloading data from that GCS bucket will not incur an egress fee.

Comment: Thanks - I got my terminology wrong (edited the question). What I would like to figure out is the region, and not the zone. Unfortunately, I don't have the permission to run the `gsutil ls -Lb` command you suggested - so I guess that means there is no way for me to find out the region other than asking the people who actually own the data.

Comment: Yes, that is probably best. Note that the egress fee will apply to the owner of the bucket (excepting the case of the downloader using the requester-pays feature), so it is in their interest to suggest the right zone for you to use.

Comment: Yup, the owner of the bucket kindly replied and shared the location. Indeed, its's a requester-pays bucket, so it's in my own interest to be in the same region :)